# NX Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] - express application - unable to import ESM libs

Tags: nrwl-nx

I've recently created an nx workspace and added in an Express application. This works out-of-the-box as you would expect. However, as soon as I add a dependency to a ESM library (e.g. nanoid v4+), I'm unable to start the server and I get the following error message.

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /workspace/node_modules/nanoid/index.js not supported`

What is the correct way to configure an NX workspace and Express application so it is able to import both ESM libraries and local workspace libraries and successfully test/build/serve the application?

- `npx nx run my-express-api:test`
- `npx nx run my-express-api:build`
- `npx nx run my-express-api:serve`

---

**Attempt 1**

This is the out-of-the-box attempt

**Error:**

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /workspace/node_modules/nanoid/index.js not supported.

Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Module._load (/workspace/node_modules/@nx/js/src/executors/node/node-with-require-overrides.js:18:31)
    at Array.__webpack_modules__ (/workspace/dist/apps/my-express-api/main.js:26:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/workspace/dist/apps/my-express-api/main.js:49:41)
    at /workspace/dist/apps/my-express-api/main.js:69:18
    at /workspace/dist/apps/my-express-api/main.js:81:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/dist/apps/my-express-api/main.js:83:12)
    at Module._load (/workspace/node_modules/@nx/js/src/executors/node/node-with-require-overrides.js:10:31)
```

**Config:**

express app **tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node", "express"]
  },
  "exclude": ["jest.config.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

express app **webpack.config.js**

```
const { NxWebpackPlugin } = require('@nx/webpack');
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, '../../dist/apps/my-express-api'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new NxWebpackPlugin({
      target: 'node',
      compiler: 'tsc',
      main: './src/main.ts',
      tsConfig: './tsconfig.app.json',
      assets: ['./src/assets'],
      optimization: false,
      outputHashing: 'none',
    }),
  ],
};
```

express app **project.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-express-api",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/my-express-api/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nx/js:node",
      "defaultConfiguration": "development",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "my-express-api:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "my-express-api:build:development"
        },
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "my-express-api:build:production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

root workspace **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nx-template",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.11.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "nanoid": "^5.0.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "11.11.0",
    "@nx/eslint": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/express": "18.0.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

---

**Attempt 2**

Modifying tsconfig/webpack settings.

These modifications aren't ideal but this does allow me to import ESM libraries. However, I now can't import local workspace libraries.

**Error:**

```
ERROR in ./apps/my-express-api/src/main.ts 9:0-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'test-lib' in '/workspace/apps/my-express-api/src'
resolve 'test-lib' in '/workspace/apps/my-express-api/src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /workspace/apps/my-express-api/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    resolve as module
      /workspace/apps/my-express-api/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /workspace/apps/my-express-api/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /workspace/apps/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /workspace/node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: /workspace/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/test-lib)
            no extension
              /workspace/node_modules/test-lib doesn't exist
            .js
              /workspace/node_modules/test-lib.js doesn't exist
            .mjs
              /workspace/node_modules/test-lib.mjs doesn't exist
            .ts
              /workspace/node_modules/test-lib.ts doesn't exist
            .mts
              /workspace/node_modules/test-lib.mts doesn't exist
        /workspace/node_modules/test-lib doesn't exist
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
```

**Config:**

**project.json**

```
...
    "build": {
  "executor": "@nx/webpack:webpack",
  "dependsOn": ["lint"],
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "target": "node",
    "compiler": "tsc",
    "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-express-api",
    "main": "apps/my-express-api/src/main.ts",
    "tsConfig": "apps/my-express-api/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": ["apps/my-express-api/src/assets"],
    "isolatedConfig": true,
    "webpackConfig": "apps/my-express-api/webpack.config.cjs",
  }
},
...
```

**jest.config.json**

```
/* eslint-disable */
export default {
  displayName: 'new-app-server',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[tj]s$': ['ts-jest', { tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json' }],
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/my-express-api',
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-express-api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "commonjs"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["node", "express"]
  },
  "exclude": ["jest.config.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

**webpack.config.cjs**

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development', // or 'production' for production mode
  entry: './apps/my-express-api/src/main.ts', // Entry point of your Express application
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/apps/my-express-api'),
    filename: 'main.mjs',
    module: true,
    libraryTarget: 'module',
    chunkFormat: 'module',
    chunkFilename: 'main.mjs',
    library: {
      type: 'module',
    },
    environment: {
      module: true,
    },
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: 'node-module',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.ts', '.mts'], // Support both .js and .mjs extensions for ESM
    extensionAlias: {
      '.js': ['.ts', '.js'],
      '.mjs': ['.mts', '.mjs'],
      '.cjs': ['.cts', '.cjs'],
    },
  },
  target: 'node', // Important for server-side applications
  externals: [nodeExternals({ importType: 'module' })], // Exclude node_modules from the bundle
  externalsPresets: {
    node: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // Add any necessary loaders or rules here
      { test: /\.([cm]?ts|tsx)$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ],
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    // Add any necessary plugins here
  ],
};
```

---

**Attempt 3**

Using **@nx/esbuild:esbuild**

I thought I had solved it with this solution. If I import esm libraries (e.g. nanoid v4+) then I no longer get the `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]` error and I am able to build/serve my application.

The problem occurs when I try to import a workspace js library

**Error:**

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@myorg/mylib' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

**Config:**

**project.json**

```
...
  "build": {
  "executor": "@nx/esbuild:esbuild",
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-express-api",
    "main": "apps/my-express-api/src/main.ts",
    "tsConfig": "apps/my-express-api/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": [],
    "generatePackageJson": true,
    "format": ["esm"],
    "platform": "node",
    "bundle": true
  }
},
...
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-express-api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module"
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    //    "outDir": "../../../dist/out-tsc",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["ES2021"],
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ES2021",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["node", "express"]
  },
  "exclude": ["jest.config.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
}
```

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
...
    "paths": {
      "@myorg/mylib": ["libs/mylib/src/index.ts"],
    }
...
```

---

[Source code examples](https://github.com/b-simpson12/esm-test)

---

**Edits**

- Updated sandbox link
- Added detailed error message
- Added attempt 2 details
- Added attempt 3 details
- Added link to Github repo with all attempts and more